# LinkedList segmentation fault when inserting Node at Back

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am new to C and I am attempting to create a LinkedList to store ingredients from a rawRecipe array (marked with a "1"). However, I seem to be getting a segmentation fault. By doing some preliminary diagnostic, it seems to be coming from from insertIngredientAtBack function, but I can't pinpoint where. Could you please tell me what I am overlooking?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char *rawRecipes[]={

"0Broccoli Coleslaw",

"1olive oil",

"1white vinegar",

"1broccoli",

"0Creamy Broccoli Salad",

"1broccoli",

"1white sugar",

"1red onion",

"1white wine vinegar",

"0Minnesota Broccoli Salad",

"1eggs",

"1broccoli",

"1red onion",

""

};

//ASSUMING THESE LIMITS
#define MAXRECIPES 30 /* max # of recipes */
#define MAXINGREDIENTTYPES 250 /* max # of ingredient types */
#define MAXINGREDIENTS 250 /* max # of ingredients all recipes */
#define MAXCHARS 100 /* max characters for recipe or ingredient*/
#define INGMAX 25 /* max ingredient count per recipe*/

// structure declarations

struct Ingredient {

    char IngName[MAXCHARS];
    char recipe[MAXRECIPES][MAXCHARS]; //unused member for now.
    int recipeNum;
    struct Ingredient* next;

};

typedef struct Ingredient Ingredients;


typedef struct linkedListIngredient {

    Ingredients* head;

} linkedListIngredient;


typedef struct {

    char recipe[MAXINGREDIENTS][MAXCHARS];

} records;


Ingredients* createIngredientNode(char value[]) {

    Ingredients* newNode = (Ingredients*)malloc(sizeof(Ingredients));

    if (newNode != NULL) {
        strcpy(newNode->IngName, value);
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->recipeNum = 0;
        return newNode;
    }

    printf("Failed to create an ingredients node\n");
    exit(1);

}

bool IngredientNodeEmpty(linkedListIngredient* list2) {

    if (list2->head == NULL) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// append a struct to the back of LinkedList
bool insertIngredientAtBack(linkedListIngredient* list2, char value[]) {

    Ingredients* current = list2->head;

    if (IngredientNodeEmpty(list2)) {
        list2->head = createIngredientNode(value);
        return true;
    }

    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = createIngredientNode(value); 

        if (current->next != NULL) {
            return true;
        }

        else {
            printf("Failed to add Ingredient at back\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}



void convertInputToDataStructure(linkedListIngredient* list2, records* items){


    char ingredientList[MAXINGREDIENTTYPES][MAXCHARS];
    int index;
    int globalIndex;

    // Code to find Ingredients and store them in ingredientList.
    for(index = 0, globalIndex = 0; (strcmp(items->recipe[globalIndex],"") != 0); globalIndex++) {

        if(strncmp(items->recipe[globalIndex], "1", 1) == 0) {
            strcpy(ingredientList[index], (items->recipe[globalIndex])+1);
            printf("%s\n", ingredientList[index]);
            index++;

        }   
    }

    printf("%d\n", index);
        // creating a  duplicated Ingredient LinkedList:
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        // evaluating and checking the function to add LinkedList for Ingredient
        insertIngredientAtBack(list2, ingredientList[i]);
    }
}


void ListAllIngredients(linkedListIngredient* list2) {

    Ingredients* current = list2->head;

    int counter = 1;

    while(current->next != NULL) {

        printf("Ingredient #%d: %s\n", counter, current->IngName);
        counter++;
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("Recipe #%d: %s\n", counter, current->IngName);

}


int main(void) {

    // instantiating the structures for linkedlist access
    linkedListIngredient list2;

    // holds database for ingredients and recipes
    records items;

    // copying all values from rawRecipies.h
    int i;
    for(i = 0; (strcmp(rawRecipes[i], "") != 0); i++) {
        strcpy(items.recipe[i], rawRecipes[i]);
    }

    // first move data from rawRecipes.h to a data structure
    convertInputToDataStructure(&list2, &items);

    ListAllIngredients(&list2);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I didn't encounter any segmentation fault when running the posted code.  Are you doing anything differently than what you posted? Also, what is the rationale for this struct? (struct linkedListIngredient).  Could probably simplify this chunk of code without it.

Comment: @PatrickOfThings what's happening in OP's code is most likely some kind of undefined behavior which does not necessarily mean you will get a segmentation fault (though you *might* get one, as OP does).

Comment: @PatrickOfThings and Marco: You are right. It seems I am only getting a segmentation fault when I am running it on a specific machine. What might be undefined behavior?

Comment: How can you compile ? what is specific machine ?

Comment: Possibly try adding some print statements to the insertIngredientAtBack function to determine where it is crashing.  Post the output if you can't narrow it down.

Comment: I tried it on a Windows 10 machine with MSVC compiler which works and MinGw GCC compiler which fails with segmentation fault. This is because `linkedListIngredient list2;` in `main()` has not been initialized in case of MinGw. After setting `list2.head = NULL;` it works.

Comment: This behavior matches C standard which says: "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate" (C99 chapter 6.7.8, paragraph 10).

Comment: @MathiasSchmid thank you, that was indeed the problem! I was under the false belief that a pointer not pointing to anything points absolutely to NULL. Seems like that is an undefined operation after all.